# SVG image get's messed up when I put it into html

Tags: php, html, svg

I have been starting using SVG recently and I love it. There so clean, cool and easy to design.

Well I stumbled across a issue when I tried to one of my  svg's into html (Works with every one of my svgs except this one). It works totally fine if I call it as a image (`<img src="hill.svg"></img>`) but when I try to use it 
either with PHP(`include 'hill.svg';`) or just straight up passing it in on the index files, it messes up.
[Here's an image. Messed up svg top left and the working on the full screen. Same file just that the working one is imbedded with "background-image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9dZB.png)

It kinds of look like the background is turnt into one of those "missing- image-icons"

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Svg: https://pastebin.com/RsSAGv8M

Comment: What's the SVG?

Comment: I'll add it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some raster images linked in your SVG:

- 947B2F3D9DDD76B8.png (two times),
- 947B2F3D9DDD76B9.png,
- 947B2F3D9DDD76BF.png

They are probably not available on your webserver. If the SVG is linked as an `<img>`, they are never tried to retrieve, as for security reasons all images must be self-contained. But when the SVG is embeded in a HTML page, the request fails. and some browsers show a "missing image" icon.

Either delete the `<image>` tags in your SVG file (it seems you did not miss their content?), or embed them as data URLs. (I don't know Adobe illustrator good enough to know if there is a utility to do that.)

Comment: Thank you! I removed all the images in the svg and now it works :)